# Remove Genericons Helper CSS from twentyfourteen theme

Tags: css, wp-head

I'd like to remove the genericons-css styles loaded by default into twentyfourteen theme.

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='genericons-css'  href='http://ffwdconsulting.com/wp/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/genericons/genericons.css?ver=3.0.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

I followed [How to remove CSS file in the header using Wordpress functions?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/85512/how-to-remove-css-file-in-the-header-using-wordpress-functions) with this code:

```
function dequeue_my_css() {
  wp_dequeue_style('genericons-css');
  wp_deregister_style('genericons-css');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','dequeue_my_css');
```

but doesn't work. Link to css still shows up in the header.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you're trying to deregister a stylesheet that doesn't exist. Here is how the genericon stylesheet is enqueued in twenty fourteen

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'genericons', get_template_directory_uri() . '/genericons/genericons.css', array(), '3.0.2' );
```

You are trying to dequeue the stylesheet file name. Here is the [`wp_enqueue_style()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style) function

```
wp_enqueue_style( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $media );
```

The important part here is the `$handle`

> $handle (string) (required) Name used as a handle for the stylesheet.

You should use the `$handle` if you need to dequeue a stylesheet. Another thing to remember, you are running a child theme (I really hope so). Child theme functions are loaded first, so you will need to give your deregister function a priority of more than 10, otherwise your functions will not work.

Here is the working function

```
function dequeue_my_css() {
  wp_dequeue_style('genericons');
  wp_deregister_style('genericons');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','dequeue_my_css', 100);
```

In the twenty fourteen theme, this will however break the complete styling of your theme. Unfortunately the author has made the main stylesheet dependant on the genericon stylesheet, so if you dequeue the genericon stylesheet, you "dequeue" the main stylesheet as well.

Comment: well, I had tried that but the function didn't remove the link to the genericons stylesheet! I will probably end up going a different route – as I had tried building a child theme based on twentyfourteen. but if everything breaks then I might just start from scratch. or... I see now where the parent theme's function file adds the 'genericons' styles. and will disable that. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one solution you may consider considering what @goose has already stated:

You could and should always create a child theme so why not copy over the parent themes style sheet and dequeue your genericons and then enqueue your child themes style sheet.

```
function dequeue_twenty_fourteen_css() {
  wp_dequeue_style('genericons');
  wp_deregister_style('genericons');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','dequeue_twenty_fourteen_css', 100);


wp_enqueue_style( 'twenty-fourteen-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array(), '1.0.0' );
```

You'd also add something like this to the header the the style.css file in your child theme after copying over the parent themes style sheet.

```
/*
Theme Name: 2014 Child
Description:    Child Theme for TWenty Fourteen
Author: Brad Dalton http://wpsites.net
Template: twentyfourteen
*/

@import url("../twentyfourteen/style.css");
```

Tested and works.

Comment: Crappy that you need to do it this way, but I really don't see any other way of doing it. It is a shame that the authors made the main stylesheet dependable on genericons. +1

Comment: Agree @goose. Not sure how it made it past the theme review team.